# Determine location of matplotlib table elements in final PDF output

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf

I have a `matplotlib.pyplot.table` generated as part of a plot which is then saved to a PDF.

I wish to overlay a number of clickable elements onto the PDF after generating it (actually overlaid hyperlinks using `PyPDF2`), but to do that, I need to know exactly where each of the table cells is on the final PDF. PDF locations seem to be measured from the [bottom left corner with 72 points to the inch](https://www.pdfscripting.com/public/PDF-Page-Coordinates.cfm).

If I generate a table with the code below, I can see that each cell in the table contains information such as `Rectangle(xy=(0.05, 0.512264), width=0.1,` etc. However this only seems to give me the location of the cell relative to its own `ax` object, which may itself be scaled or stretched into the final PDF document depending on what else is in the plot.

Is there some trickery/transformation that allows me to determine the final location of a table cell in the output PDF in physical units, ie. points/inches/cm?

As a quick follow up - notice how I have specified the `figsize=(16, 9)` - is this a guaranteed size for the final plot in matplotlib regardless subplots, axis labels, super titles etc, or if not, under what conditions will the figure come out a different size/shape?

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_to_table = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 4)), 
    columns=list('ABCD'),
    index = list('WXYZ')
)

colWidths = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3] #Just for demo purposes 

x_scale=1;y_scale=1 # I sometimes adjust these scaling factors to make things look less cramped

# Plot the most basic table by itself

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9)) #I want this plot to nicely take up a standard monitor
ax_table = ax.table(cellText=df_to_table.to_numpy(),
                  rowLabels=df_to_table.index,
                  colLabels=df_to_table.columns,
                  colWidths=colWidths,
                  loc='center' # This seems to center the table vertically in ax
                    )
ax_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
ax_table.set_fontsize(14)

ax_table.scale(x_scale, y_scale) # Stretch either way

# Hide axes and border
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.box(on=None)

plt.savefig('test.pdf', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About page size: `figsize=(16, 9)` determines the size of the canvas and should be the final size of the image. *However*, when you save your file with `bbox_inches='tight'` the final image size will be modified to accommodate all the artists. It can be shrunk or enlarged depending on the placement of the axes and artists on the page. If you want to have a consistent image size, you should not include that option when calling `savefig()`

For your main question:

You can easily obtain the coordinates of the cell in `inches` using the `fig.dpi_scale_trans` transform (see [Transformation Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) for further information).

for instance, the bounding box of the first cell can be obtained in inches coordinates as follow:

```
cell = ax_table.get_celld()[(1,0)]
bbox_in = fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted().transform_bbox(ax.transAxes.transform_bbox(cell.get_bbox()))
```

> ```
> > bbox_in.bounds  # returns x,y,width,height in inches
> (2.6200000000000028,
> 4.538333333333332,
> 1.2400000000000002,
> 0.16666666666666696)
> ```

If you need the coordinates in points, you simply have to multiply the coordinates by 72 (1 pt = 1/72 inches). You can create a custom transform to do this for you also.

```
in2pt = matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().scale(72)
bbox_pt = in2pt.transform_bbox(bbox_in)
```

> ```
> >bbox_pt.bounds
> (188.6400000000002, 326.75999999999993, 89.27999999999997, 12.0)
> ```

According to my tests, this seems to match the position in the PDF, at least in terms of height/width. Let me know if that matches what you are trying to do with `PyPDF2`, otherwise, you'll have to share some code that use `PyPDF2` so that I can see how to get them to match.

Comment: Hi Diziet, thank you for the comprehensive answer, that is exactly what I needed :)